# DOMDocument: Ignore Duplicate Element IDs

Tags: php, domdocument, tidy

I'm putting some page content (which has been run through Tidy, but doesn't need to be if this is a source of problems) into `DOMDocument` using `DOMDocument::loadHTML`.

It's coming up with various errors:

> ID x already defined in Entity, line X

Is there any way to make either `DOMDocument` (or Tidy) ignore or strip out duplicate element IDs, so it will actually create the `DOMDocument`?

Thanks. :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A quick search on the subject reveals this (incorrect) bug report:

http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=46136

The last reply states the following:

> You're using HTML 4 rules to load an
> XHTML document. Either use the  load()
> method to parse as XML or the
> libxml_use_internal_errors()  function
> to ignore the warnings.

I can't be sure if you are encountering this problem for the same reasons, since you did not include a reference to the HTML page being loaded. In any case, using [`libxml_use_internal_errors()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.libxml-use-internal-errors.php) should at least *suppress* the error.

ID's in HTML documents are [generally unique](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#adef-id), so the **best solution** would still be validating your document, if at all possible.

Answer (score 0):

By definition, IDs are unique. If they are not, you should use classes instead (nor names, where it applies).
I doubt you can force XML tools to ignore duplicate IDs, that will make them handle an invalid XML document.

Answer (score 0):

Use Exceptions to treat duplicate IDs, and rename the second id.
Or maybe, combine elements in sub-elements of same parent with the ID.

IDs are unique in an XML file (in the rootElement of XMLTree)