# Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML() [domdocument.loadhtml]

Tags: php

After installing a plug in on my site I now have the error

> Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML() [domdocument.loadhtml]: ID tribe-events-s already defined in Entity, line: 5 in /home/flatoute/public_html/wp-content/themes/yoo_revista_wp/warp/helpers/dom.php on line 44

Well to me it looks like the problem is in the dom.php file, When I open the dom.php file there is nothing inside of it except this %s a percentage sign with a lower case s

As I've bought the plug in and the theme does anyone know what %s actually is or how to get rid of the warning message on my site?

I've sent emails to the developers of the theme and plug in, the developers of the plug in say it's nothing to do with them it's theme based, the developers of the theme/ well I doubt I'll hear anything back from them as their customer support is non existant!

Comment: It's pretty hard to tell what `%s` is without sharing any code. My guess is it is used in a `printf()`. BTW doesn't the error tell you what's wrong with your document? The same ID is used more then once in the DOM.

Comment: Well there is nothing in the dom file apart from the %s.

The only other thing I could think would be the [domdocument.loadhtml] when I click domdocument.loadhtml thats in the warning message above  I get the 404 error

Not Found

The requested URL /domdocument.loadhtml was not found on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/415927/domdocument-ignore-duplicate-element-ids  Basically it's a bug