# How to alter anchor tags and image tags to add target = '_blank' attribute using Drupal 7 or PHP

Tags: php, html, drupal, drupal-7

I would like to know a way to alter anchor tags and image tags to add `target='_blank'` attribute.

I rendered content from external source using `file_get_contents()` and assigned it to a variable. Now I want to alter the variable and assign `target='_blank'` attribute to anchor tag.

Is it possible to do it in Drupal7 way or in PHP way ?

```
<?php
$data=file_get_contents('https://example.com/live/widget/1');
?>
```

**print_r($data);**

```html
<html>
<div>
  <span class="lw_item_thumb1">
      <a href="https://example.com/#!view/event/event_id/1">
        <img src="https://example.com/live/image/gid/2/width/80/height/80/crop/1/src_region/0,0,3200,2400/example.rev.12345.jpg" alt="Floor" class="lw_image" width="80" height="80" srcset="https://example.com/live/image/scale/2x/gid/2/width/80/height/80/crop/1/src_region/0,0,3200,2400/example.rev.12345.jpg 2x, https://example.com/live/image/scale/3x/gid/2/width/80/height/80/crop/1/src_region/0,0,3200,2400/example.rev.12345.jpg 3x" data-max-w="3200" data-max-h="2400"/>
      </a>
    </span>
  <span class="lw_item_thumb2">
      <a href="https://example.com/#!view/event/event_id/2">
        <img src="https://example.com/live/image/gid/2/width/80/height/80/crop/1/src_region/0,0,3200,2400/example.rev.12345.jpg" alt="Floor" class="lw_image" width="80" height="80" srcset="https://example.com/live/image/scale/2x/gid/2/width/80/height/80/crop/1/src_region/0,0,3200,2400/example.rev.12345.jpg 2x, https://example.com/live/image/scale/3x/gid/2/width/80/height/80/crop/1/src_region/0,0,3200,2400/example.rev.12345.jpg 3x" data-max-w="3200" data-max-h="2400"/>
      </a>
    </span>
</div>

</html>
```

I want anchor tags to be changes as

```
<a href="https://example.com/#!view/event/event_id/1" target='_blank'>
```

**PS:** I want to avoid using Javascript and want to do it with PHP or Drupal way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [`DOMDocument`](http://php.net/domdocument) to parse the HTML, [`getElementsByTagName()`](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.getelementsbytagname.php) to find `<a>` tags, and [`setAttribute()`](http://php.net/manual/en/domelement.setattribute.php) to add the `target` attribute.

In the code below, I've included the HTML inline, but, of course, you can use `$data=file_get_contents('https://example.com/live/widget/1');` instead of `$data = '<html>....</html>';`.

```
$data = '<html>
<div>
  <span class="lw_item_thumb1">
      <a href="https://example.com/#!view/event/event_id/1">
        <img src="https://example.com/live/image/gid/2/width/80/height/80/crop/1/src_region/0,0,3200,2400/example.rev.12345.jpg" alt="Floor" class="lw_image" width="80" height="80" srcset="https://example.com/live/image/scale/2x/gid/2/width/80/height/80/crop/1/src_region/0,0,3200,2400/example.rev.12345.jpg 2x, https://example.com/live/image/scale/3x/gid/2/width/80/height/80/crop/1/src_region/0,0,3200,2400/example.rev.12345.jpg 3x" data-max-w="3200" data-max-h="2400"/>
      </a>
    </span>
  <span class="lw_item_thumb2">
      <a href="https://example.com/#!view/event/event_id/2">
        <img src="https://example.com/live/image/gid/2/width/80/height/80/crop/1/src_region/0,0,3200,2400/example.rev.12345.jpg" alt="Floor" class="lw_image" width="80" height="80" srcset="https://example.com/live/image/scale/2x/gid/2/width/80/height/80/crop/1/src_region/0,0,3200,2400/example.rev.12345.jpg 2x, https://example.com/live/image/scale/3x/gid/2/width/80/height/80/crop/1/src_region/0,0,3200,2400/example.rev.12345.jpg 3x" data-max-w="3200" data-max-h="2400"/>
      </a>
    </span>
</div>

</html>';

$doc = new DOMDocument();
// $doc->loadXML($data);
$doc->loadHTML($data, LIBXML_NOWARNING); /* Thanks @NigelRen - see comments below */
$elms = $doc->getElementsByTagName('a');
foreach ($elms as $elm) {
    if (!$elm->hasAttribute('target')) {
        $elm->setAttribute('target','_blank');
    }
}
echo $doc->saveHTML();
```

Outputs:

```
<html>
<div>
  <span class="lw_item_thumb1">
      <a href="https://example.com/#!view/event/event_id/1" target="_blank">
        <img src="https://example.com/live/image/gid/2/width/80/height/80/crop/1/src_region/0,0,3200,2400/example.rev.12345.jpg" alt="Floor" class="lw_image" width="80" height="80" srcset="https://example.com/live/image/scale/2x/gid/2/width/80/height/80/crop/1/src_region/0,0,3200,2400/example.rev.12345.jpg 2x, https://example.com/live/image/scale/3x/gid/2/width/80/height/80/crop/1/src_region/0,0,3200,2400/example.rev.12345.jpg 3x" data-max-w="3200" data-max-h="2400">
      </a>
    </span>
  <span class="lw_item_thumb2">
      <a href="https://example.com/#!view/event/event_id/2" target="_blank">
        <img src="https://example.com/live/image/gid/2/width/80/height/80/crop/1/src_region/0,0,3200,2400/example.rev.12345.jpg" alt="Floor" class="lw_image" width="80" height="80" srcset="https://example.com/live/image/scale/2x/gid/2/width/80/height/80/crop/1/src_region/0,0,3200,2400/example.rev.12345.jpg 2x, https://example.com/live/image/scale/3x/gid/2/width/80/height/80/crop/1/src_region/0,0,3200,2400/example.rev.12345.jpg 3x" data-max-w="3200" data-max-h="2400">
      </a>
    </span>
</div>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I am getting an error as 'Warning: DOMDocument::loadXML(): Extra content at the end of the document in Entity,' and data is not being displayed.

Comment: Would it be useful to add an option which checks if there is already a target attribute and not overwrite it.

Comment: Change `loadXML()` to `loadHTML()`

Comment: Oh, right @NigelRen. Thank you. I've add the test with `hasAttribute()`.

Comment: @NigelRen after changing it I am getting this error 'Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML(): ID :ak.co already defined in Entity'

Comment: @miststudent2011 The HTML that you're trying to load seems to be invalid, that's why you get this warning. Try to use `loadHTML($data, LIBXML_NOWARNING)`.

Comment: @Syscall trying that too displays the error I think its a bug not sure. Source : https://stackoverflow.com/q/415927/6687229

Comment: Sorry @miststudent2011, I didn't understand. You want to show, hide or get errors?  `libxml_use_internal_errors()` is used to get errors using `libxml_get_errors()`.

Comment: @Syscall Thank you for your answer I have upvoted your answer I will look for some time and check if anyone can post answer in Drupal way.If not I will select it as approved answer.

Comment: @miststudent2011 Ok, no problem. You could try to add `libxml_use_internal_errors(true)` at the beginning, and also use `loadHTML($data, LIBXML_NOERROR)`.